# How to push a View from bottom using swiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I am drag Image using a drag Gesture. When the gestures action ends a another View push from bottom of the screen to top of the screen.

Already am try **NavigationLink()**, But NavigationLink doesn't support inside the gesture action.

How to handle this use case ?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63598406/12299030? Or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/61811749/12299030?

Comment: You can use programmatic navigation. Essentially, you trigger the `NavigationLink` with a binding that you change inside the drag.